# How do I find the amount of free space on my hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-usage

Is there a way to quickly check the amount of free / used disk space in Ubuntu?

I would assume you could right click on 'file system' in the file browser and choose 'properties' or something but there is no such option.

Answer (score 795, accepted):

Open **System Monitor** from Dash and select the **Filesystems** tab.

[image]

Or alternatively open a Terminal and type:

```
df -h
```

Comment: thanks! got me what i need. But it is kind of a bummer that there's no intuitive way to check the hd usage. I imagine most people would get frustrated trying to figure it out.

Comment: Well. Every time you are in a folder in nautilus, it says at the bottom how much space is left on the device.

Comment: @greg: Actually, it isn't as straightforward as you might think, since the UNIX way of mounting filesystems means that any folder's contents can potentially exist on different disks or partitions. Thus, any method of checking free space must explicitly account for this.

Comment: `df -h --total`

Comment: `df` for used and free space in bytes,  `df -m` for space in units of 1MB,  `df -h` for largest available unit.  You will also get `% usage`,  it remains same with all the above though.

Comment: How about using free command to find out disk space availability..  ;) ??

Comment: Faster opening: `$> mate-system-monitor` or `$> gnome-system-monitor` directly from command line.

Comment: just to show only total with header `df --total -h | grep -e total -e Filesystem` But if you have multiple drives, it might not show them separately.  try `df --help` for more info.

Answer (score 306):

You can use `baobab`, or similar tools such as `kdirstat` or `filelight`, to see what files are using up your disk space.

Baobab is also called `Disk Usage Analyzer` on Ubuntu.

Here's a sample screenshot of `baobab`:

[image: baobab]

Below is a sample screenshot of `filelight`:

[image: filelight]

For a command line option, I prefer to use `ncdu`:

[image: ncdu]

You can drill into sub-folders to get total relative disk usage on the sub-folders. It's turtles all the way down. More nifty than `du -sh` on remote machines.

Comment: Was not aware of `ncdu` until now. VERY useful program. I went from issuing `du -sk * | sort -n` to using `ncdu`.  While I do enjoy being able to issue a few handy commands in a terminal or even making aliases out of them, no sense reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Enableing now, only v1.8 though :(

Comment: `ncdu` is a great tool, very fast, very awesome.

Comment: kdirstat was remade as `QDirStat` and it is insanely fast and an excellent graphical representation of drive / (recursive) folder usage.

Comment: ncdu is a great tool. We use it in our team to find the top users/hoggers

Comment: I would recommend when using `ncdu` to use it with the `-x` switch so that it doesn't try to count mounted devices in the disk space counts.  `ncdu -x /` can show you from your root `/` on.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: `ncdu` is the best. Quick, easy to use. I wish it would be a better-known command.

Comment: This should be an example answer for everybody - GUI solution as main thing, USABLE terminal solution as a backup/fallback solution (not some freaky grep-fruits)

Comment: Indeed ncdu pwns! This should definitely be the best answer!

Comment: [Here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ncdu.1.html) is ncdu man pages.

Answer (score 230):

If like me all you need is the total of disk space used then just use the following command.

```
df -h --total
```

Here's a sample output with the total shown at the end

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            478M     0  478M   0% /dev
tmpfs           100M  4.5M   95M   5% /run
/dev/vda1        20G  3.3G   16G  18% /
tmpfs           497M     0  497M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           497M     0  497M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/0
total            22G  3.3G   17G  17% -
```

I wrote a post about it: [How Do I Find the Amount of Free Space on My Hard Drive with Command Line?](https://ahmadawais.com/ubuntu-find-amount-free-space-hard-drive-command-line/)

Comment: `df -h --total | command grep total | df -h --total | command grep total | head -c-3 && echo ''` will show only the `total` line

Answer (score 174):

`gnome-system-monitor` or `df -h` or `lsblk`

Other useful utilities are `baobab`.

Comment: Agree with user606723. Cool utility baobab :)

Comment: `lsblk` lists the size of each partition, not the free space.

Answer (score 30):

Free/used disk space is always related to a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning)

First you need to decide which partition you are interested in.

```
root@pc:~# df -h
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1               28G   26G  643M  98% /
none                   4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                   3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs                  790M  1.5M  789M   1% /run
/dev/sda6              887G  685G  158G  82% /home
```

In my case I am interested in the `/` since it has 98% in use. In other words it is nearly full.

Now I use this command to see which files and directories contain the most bytes:

```
root@pc:~# du -ax / | sort -rn > /var/tmp/du-root-$(date --iso).log
```

Above command can take some time. If you are really unlucky the result is too big for `/var/tmp`. Then you need an other destination. Maybe a temporary mounted usb memory stick.

Here are the first lines of my result:

```
root@pc:~# less /var/tmp/du-root-$(date --iso).log
26692380        /
9875188 /usr
8931652 /var
4057324 /var/log
4038176 /var/log/bootchart
3784016 /usr/share
2934248 /lib
2799204 /usr/lib
2785176 /lib/modules
2617048 /var/lib
2141124 /usr/src
1834444 /var/lib/docker
1817372 /var/lib/docker/aufs
1817076 /var/lib/docker/aufs/diff
1769612 /localhome
1338484 /tmp
```

Why is `/var/log/bootchart` that big? .... That is an other question ...

Answer (score 13):

There are a number of ways to do this.

- Enable the status bar in the View menu in Nautilus. This will place a bar at the bottom of all nautilus windows telling you the free space.
- Use the File Systems System Monitor to view a list of all disks and their free space.
- Use the Disk Usage Analyzer to get a listing of all directories on your system and how much free space they take up.
- Go to any folder in nautilus and right click the background. Open the properties window to check the free space.
- Run the command `df -h`.

Comment: Disk Usage Analyzer was what I needed, a simple Windows-style per-drive breakdown (used / total) rather than a bunch of directories which are on the same drive.

Answer (score 13):

There's df information all over the net, but I like output that's simple and easy to read.

If you run

```
df -h --total
```

the bottom line in the output will give you exactly how much is left in your system, as well as how much is used etc.

The other option is to use

```
df -h --total | grep total
```

which will show it in one line as

- (1) total space
- (2) total space used
- (3) total space still available
- (4) percentage of drive used.

All of this in gigabytes.

I mapped this to a shell command `dspace` and when I type that into terminal it instantly shows me my disk space usage.

You can even write little shell commands that will monitor it and alert you if you get too low etc.

Answer (score 7):

Another way! Right click on computer in Nautilus (file explorer) and click properties. It displays how much free and used space is on your hard drive. [image]

Comment: is there a command for this?

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a little hack for this with a command line and gui version.  It's rather hard-coded, so may need some tweaks.  Also, the gui version appears to use a proportional font that messes up the alignment of the displayed output.  These scripts could be put in your path somewhere (like in $HOME/bin) and you can create an icon for the gui script on your desktop or panel.

```
#!/bin/bash
## jdf - Copyleft 04/25/2009 - JPmicrosystems - GPL
## Free space on disk
## Custom df output
## Human readable (-h)
## sorted by file system name

## Make a temporary file and put the following awk program in it
AWK=$(/bin/mktemp -q /tmp/jdf.XXXXXX)

## PROG is quoted to prevent all shell expansions
## in the awk program
cat <<'PROG' > ${AWK}
## Won't work if mount points are longer than 21 characters

BEGIN {
  ## Use fixed length fields to avoid problems with
  ## mount point or file system names with embedded blanks
  FIELDWIDTHS = "11 11 6 6 5 5 21"
  printf "\n%s\n\n", "                    Available Disk Space"
  printf     "%s\n", "Mount Point          Avail Size  Used  Use%  Filesystem Type"
}

## Eliminate some filesystems
## That are usually not of interest
## anything not starting with a /

! /^\// { next }

## Rearrange the columns and print

{
  TYP=$2
  gsub("^ *", "", TYP)
  printf "%-21s%6s%6s%5s%5s %s%s\n", $7, $5, $3, $4, $6, $1, TYP
}

END { print "" }
PROG

df -hT | tail -n +2 | sort | gawk -f ${AWK}

rm -f ${AWK}
```

Sample output:

```
                   Available Disk Space

Mount Point          Avail Size  Used  Use%  Filesystem Type
/                      22G  30G  6.6G   24%  /dev/sda6  ext4    
/media/dataspace       44G 155G  105G   71%  /dev/sda8  ext3    
/home                 5.5G  32G   25G   82%  /dev/sda9  ext3
```

Gui version:

```
#!/bin/bash
jdf | zenity  --title "Available Disk Space" --text-info --width=500 --height=300 --timeout=60
```

New Gui Version with fonts fixed using yad

```
#!/bin/bash

jdf | yad  --fontname="DejaVu Sans Mono 12" --title "Available Disk Space" --text-info --width=650 --height=300
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `dconf-editor` or `gsettings` (`sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`) you can enable the default behavior of the status bar.

Type this on your terminal to enable the status bar by default

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.window-state start-with-status-bar true
```

Type this on your terminal to disable the status bar by default

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.window-state start-with-status-bar false
```

After that you will have the statusbar opened by default on Nautilus, no need to run anything else.

Answer (score 2):

In `lubuntu` you can do as follows:

1- `Start Button` > `Accessories` > `Disks`

2- `Start Button` > `Preferences` > `Disks`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

lsblk with some extra options works pretty well.
`lsblk -o NAME,MOUNTPOINT,SIZE,FSUSED,FSAVAIL,FSUSE%`

You can customize the columns. If you want more device level info add `VENDOR,LABEL,UUID`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Ubuntu with [MATE DE](http://mate-desktop.org/) ([Ubuntu MATE](http://ubuntu-mate.org/)) you can use `MATE Disk Usage Analyzer`:

- its icon is located in *Applications->System Tools*
- it is a part of [`mate-utils` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/mate-utils/filelist)
- its executable is named `mate-disk-usage-analyzer`
- its screenshot is presented below:

  [image: MATE Disk Usage Analyzer]

  even on latest 18.04 LTS it looks traditionally nice.

Answer (score 0):

[Filelight](https://utils.kde.org/projects/filelight/) is the best graphical program to find out the usage of some mounted partitions. Doesn't show everything which is mounted by the system, but displays enough data which should suffice an average user. Does not require root to work, can be run as a regular user. Belongs to KDE.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Utilities / Disks it will give you the percentage of use. Linux is divided in to two SDAs, the first is for the OS, the second is for the files (available space)

Comment: Note that there is a generalization in this answer: while in the past by default the installer created two partitions on the disk which will be referenced by two block devices which may be `/dev/sda*` for root filesystem `/` and swap  partition ( for relocated memory pages ), the more recent versions of Ubuntu opt to have only one root partition with root filesystem and a swap file. Note also that for NVMe drives it may be `/dev/nvme0n*` block device

Answer (score 0):

A command-line option: `parted` in command mode:

```
$ parted /dev/nvme0n1 unit GiB print free
Model: Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 932GiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start    End      Size     File system  Name  Flags
        0.00GiB  0.00GiB  0.00GiB  Free Space
 1      0.00GiB  0.50GiB  0.50GiB  fat32              boot, esp
 2      0.50GiB  732GiB   731GiB   ext4
        732GiB   932GiB   200GiB   Free Space

$
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
$
$ parted --version
parted (GNU parted) 3.3
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by <http://git.debian.org/?p=parted/parted.git;a=blob_plain;f=AUTHORS>.
$
```

Taken from [this unix.stackexchange.com answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171510/36362).

Answer (score -1):

If you have facing the issue in low disk space in android studio,just delete the unwanted emulator in your AVD manager.I wasted the whole to try other things.it help full to any one.it working for me.

Comment: Downvoting for the following reason: this answer does not address what is asked in this particular question. While it is a useful solution, it is not useful in this particular context.

Answer (score -2):

Simply you can find available free space using free command ..
Here you can get clear explanation about free command usage

[using "free" command to find free space available on Linux](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_free.htm)

Comment: The `free` command is for _memory_, not for hard disks.