# How to see the size and free disk space on the / filesystem's partition?

Tags: nautilus, filesystem, disk-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find the amount of free space on my hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73160/how-do-i-find-the-amount-of-free-space-on-my-hard-drive)

In Nautilus, I can easily see the physical size (total capacity, free space, used space) of any mounted disk, e.g. those mounted under /media, by right-clicking on them where they are listed on the top of the left panel (with a disk icon), or even by right-clicking on their folder icon on the right when I'm seeing the contents of folder that contains them (e.g. /media).

But I can't do that with the partition that contains the root filesystem. How can I see the physical properties of the disk partition that is used as the / filesystem??

It is shown in the left panel of Nautilus as "File System" with an icon similar (but not identical) to that of mounted filesystems, but if I right-click on it it will only show (after the time it takes to compute it) the total size of its contents *including* other mounted filesystems, and it won't show neither the total capacity nor the free space.

Comment: Another good link is here : https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-help/disk-capacity.html

Answer (score 3):

As @Anwar mentioned, one way is to use the `df` command:

```
df -h
```

Note that `sudo` isn't required.

For a graphical application, I like GParted. It's intended to be a disk partitioner, but I find other uses for it, as well--including this one.

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `sudo df -h` command in a terminal to see the free space.

See the [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/df.1.html) for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Go in Home folder in nautilus
Right click in  window, Choose properties.

You will able to see free disk size.

Comment: It does show the free disk space but not the used one nor total capacity