# Uninstalled Virtual Box without deleting the VDI

Tags: virtualbox

I created a VM using Virtual Box, but I gave it 25 GB, and I had 15 GB free. So I deleted it, and soon, uninstalled Virtual Box, but when I open my filesystem's properties, it is full, I mean to say about 80% of it is still in use, and the vdi file isn't anywhere. How do I free it up?

Comment: That is why in the future, always use dynamic disk allocation.

Comment: What does `df -h` show?

Comment: Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda7        17G   15G 1008M  94% /

Comment: You say you "deleted it" before uninstalling VB. What does this mean?

Comment: I deleted the Virtual Machine only (not the VDI), then uninstalled Virtual Box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default your VirtualBox files should be located in  `$HOME/VirtualBox VMs/` so if you navigate there you should easily see if there are any remaining `.vdi` files still in place.

If your files were in a non-default location try running the following in a Terminal window to find them:

```
find $HOME -iname *.vdi
```

And when you find the files you can manually delete them...

**References:**

- [10.1. Where VirtualBox stores its files](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#vboxconfigdata)

Comment: I've tried that before asking that question, I think it damaged my filesystem, because it must've tried to allocate 25GB, while I had only 15 GB free.

Comment: So the `find` command had no results?

Comment: yes, no results, 100% sure.

Comment: ext4 is quite robust, it doesn't get damaged because of trying to allocate more space than it has available.

Comment: Check this question to find what is using your disk space: http://askubuntu.com/questions/73160/how-do-i-find-the-amount-of-free-space-on-my-hard-drive

Comment: Since there are multiple file formats the hard disk image could be using it might be easier to use 'find $HOME -iname *.vbox'

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall VirtualBox:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox
```

Remove all settings:

```
sudo rm ~/.config/VirtualBox/ -Rf
```