# Why is the space on my disk used up so quickly?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, storage

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10. The Ubuntu partition has 419 GB, and another 8 GB to swap. My issue is that when the installation is finished, when I log in to Ubuntu, second by second the memory space is used without my installing anything.

[image: Used 8,3G]

Then after some minutes:

[image: Used 11G]

And then after a lot of minutes:

[image: Used 48G]

[image: Used 55G]

This happens until Ubuntu runs out of space. I reinstalled Ubuntu many times but it's still happening.

**UPDATE 1**

I used ncdu command and I get it

[image: ncdu]

`df -h`

[image: df -h]

`sudo find / -xdev -type f -size +100M`

[image: find size]

**UPDATE 2**

syslog file

[image: syslog]

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/73160/how-do-i-find-the-amount-of-free-space-on-my-hard-drive/305057 for tools to analyze disk usage.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but Im a really novice, so, I dont know what to do. I execute all commands that display in the links and the output is `/var/log/syslog.1
/var/log/kern.log
/var/log/syslog
` , I dont know what to do!

Comment: Is correct delete the files `/var/log/syslog.1 /var/log/kern.log /var/log/syslog`?

Comment: Youre right, I deleted it files and my memory space decreace again. How can I fix ? I dont know what more to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , I solved my issue. The first step was see what is the files which have a lot of disk space in my machine. For that, I executed this command suggested by [dsstorefile1](https://askubuntu.com/users/799387/dsstorefile1):

`find / -xdev -type f -size +100M`

Where the most file which have disk space occupied was:

`/var/log/kern.log`
`/var/log/syslog`

Then, I opened the file `syslog` to see what is the issue which fill my syslog, and I find this issue:

`PCIe Bus Error, id=00e8`

So, searching in the internet, I came to the answer that gave me solution:

1. edit /etc/default/grub and and add pci=noaer to the line starting with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT. It will look like this:
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noaer"
2. run "sudo update-grub"
3. reboot

REFERENCE: ["PCIe Bus Error, id=00e8" both 16.04 and 17.04](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2361702)