# How to free space on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04

I am trying to install something on the Ubuntu and it returns me the message : 'no free space on device'.

I have tied 3 different ways to free some space and apparently did not succeed.

1: Synapsis is a software that helps me remove/uninstall some software but in order to access it, firstly i have to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

But since there is no space left, I can t.

2: Ubuntu software Center Is missing from my list and I have tried to install is as well

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

As in the previous case, no spae, no install done.

3: I tried line commands like

```
sudo apt-get purge <>
sudo apt-get remove <>
```

No success.

I even tried some commands like

```
df -i
```

// to see the inode usage

```
df -h
```

//to see if there are any folders that are 100% full

```
du -sh
```

//check large file , du command, short for disk usage, is used to estimate file space usage.The du command can be used to track the files and directories which are consuming excessive amount of space on hard disk drive.

Comment: i think your mean  'Synaptic'  instead  'synapsis'  .

Comment: so what is the output of `df -h`?

Comment: Are you sure the problem comes from your packages?  Did you have a look at your documents?

Comment: try using `htop` for see where is to need free space. if the problem comes from your package try using `bleachbit`.

Comment: There are TWO possible out-of-space causes, and you handle each very differently. Methods that solve one won't work at all on the other. You must answer @RoVo's question to discover which cause you have.

Comment: See all this thread https://askubuntu.com/q/73160/66509 to analyze occupied disk space. +1 to package/non-package problem. @Eveleen do you have separate `/boot` paritition. Please add output of `df -h` and `mount` to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List installed packages sorted by Size in bytes:

```
dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n' | sort -n
```

Uninstall packages you don't need:

```
sudo apt remove <package>
```

Then see if you can install `bleachbit`:

```
sudo apt install bleachbit
```

Bleachbit can free up a lot of space like temp files, thumbnails, caches, etc.

---

This will only help temporarily, your drive will fill up again. You might consider getting a bigger hard drive or if you have partitions changing partition sizes (give more to `/`) or don't use separate partitions for `/` and `/home`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to clean out more space is to clean out the Cached Packages

To clean out the cached packages folder properly, you can use this command from the shell prompt:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```