# so many number of entries in "file systems" tab in System moniter

Tags: 18.04

Hi,

I'm checking the disk usage in my ubuntu system (18.04)and I'm seeing so many entries in the File Systems tab.
Is it common to see all these or am I doing something wrong.

Attached the picture for the reference.

[image: File Systems Image]

Comment: I see nothing wrong there. What are you calling "file systems"?

Comment: @Pilot6 When i'm searching for how to find the disk space, I came across this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/73162, where it is showing only one entry. That is the reason I'm asking

Comment: There are so many because you have lots of snap applications and each have their own loop device which is a squashfs filesystem image see https://askubuntu.com/questions/834093/small-snap-loop-devices-visible-in-gnome-disk-utility-or-what-is-the-function-of