# Differences between `df -h` VS `df -h --total`

Tags: hard-drive, disk-usage

I was reading [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/73162/727107) that suggested `df -h` for checking disc space. But in the comments, another user suggested `df -h --total` and at this time has 93 upvotes.
I tried both `df -h` and `df -h --total` and the output is the same on my device.

I used `men` to see what `--total` does and this came out. I don't quite understand it either. a little elaboration would be appreciated.

> elide all entries insignificant to available space, and produce a grand total

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df -h --total` Will print a total sum(of the file systems) at the end like:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
total           930G  215G  669G  25% -
```

While `df -h` wont. Other than that, they are the same.